# switching between two redux-saga flows

Tags: redux-saga

In my scenario the user can redeem vouchers. While she is not logged in she can still test the redeem feature to understand how it works.

I have 2 flows, `notLoggedInRedeemFlow` for the case when she is not logged in and `loggedInRedeemFlow` in case she is logged in.

I have on root saga, that should start one flow and stop the other based on the users login state.

I came up with using a race between one flow and a `cancellation` action for that flow.

On app startup the `notLoggedInRedeemFlow` is active and it should end when the user logs in.

Then the `loggedInRedeemFlow` starts and runs until the user logs out.

```
function* redeemFlows() {
  while (true) {
    const result = yield race({
      fake: call(notLoggedInRedeemFlow),
      gotAccessToken: take([accountActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS, accountActions.START_SIGNUP_SUCCESS]),
    })
    yield race({
      run: call(loggedInRedeemFlow, result.gotAccessToken.payload.access_token),
      logout: take(accountActions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS),
    })
  }
}
```

My questions is if that is the best way to handle such scenario in redux-sagas?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your use case correctly, then I believe you need a REDEEM action that is fired from the UI and a saga that interprets whether you are logged in or not. If you are logged in, then PUT a REDEEM_LOGGED_IN action otherwise PUT a REDEEM_NOT_LOGGED_IN action.  And there would be sub-sagas that handle those REDEEM_LOGGED_IN and REDEEM_NOT_LOGGED_IN actions respectively.

```
import {takeLatest} from 'redux-saga';

export default function* rootSaga () {
  yield takeLatest('REDEEM', handleGenericRedeem);
  yield takeLatest('REDEEM_NOT_LOGGED_IN', handleRedeemNotLoggedIn);
  yield takeLatest('REDEEM_LOGGED_IN', handleRedeemLoggedIn);
}
```

The exact action names and whether to use takeLatest is up to you and your specific use case. You might not need nor want takeLatest, but the code snippet should give you an idea of how can solve the problem one way.